# How to use a svg inside a svg?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am using D3.js and i try to create a svg inside an svg.
For example my first svg is this:

```
  var svg = d3.selectAll('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',500)
      .attr('height',500);
```

Then i want to create a second svg inside this first one and i want it to appear at the upper right corner of my first svg. How is that possible? I thought about the attributes of width = 100 and height = 100 for the second svg. The reason for this question is, that i use the force-layout in D3.js and it can be realy big depending on the input of data. So i want to put the graph itself in the first big svg and other informations like texts in the smaller second svg. If a solution with div elements could be better, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append another SVG within the first.

```
  var svg = d3.selectAll('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',500)
      .attr('height',500);

  var innerSVG = svg.append('svg')
      .attr('width',100)
      .attr('height',100);
```

Comment: Not sure if i did it wrong. But the screen is totally white, because it is a white svg on a other white svg?

Comment: They have no default styling. They are just transparent.